# Different View on device

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a frame layout with scroll view and control view. On double tap visibility of Action bar and a control view (located at the bottom of the screen) is toggled. The application works fine on JB but on Froyo, the control view locates itself near top of the screen i.e overlapping with action bar. Also, there is a blank space between screen top and adview, on Froyo but not on JB.
status bar is not visible.

My Layouts:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/FrameLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="5dp"
android:alpha="0.95"
tools:context=".FC" >

     <RelativeLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:orientation="horizontal"
      tools:ignore="UselessParent" >

           <com.amazon.device.ads.AdLayout
            android:id="@+id/ad_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:minHeight="50dp" />

     <ScrollView
         android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
         android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
         android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
         android:layout_below="@+id/ad_view"
         android:fillViewport="true" >

         <RelativeLayout
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:text="Body" />

         </RelativeLayout>

     </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/controlview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|fill_horizontal"
    android:background="@color/WhiteSmoke"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
    tools:ignore="UselessParent" >

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBarScroll"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/TVMainaofb" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TVMainaofb"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"            
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:minHeight="50dp"
        android:text="365/365\n(100%)"
        android:textColor="@color/Black" />

</RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Can put a screen shot of both devices? So i can figure out what expect problem occurred.

Comment: i don't have min req reputation to post images.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at i made some change in your code.

FILL_PARENT which renamed MATCH_PARENT in API Level 8 and higher.

Example: If you use write app for both 1.6 and 2.2, you will use fill_parent.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/FrameLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="5dp"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:alpha="0.95"
tools:context=".FC" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:ignore="UselessParent" >

    <com.amazon.device.ads.AdLayout
        android:id="@+id/ad_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:minHeight="50dp" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ad_view"
        android:fillViewport="true" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:text="Body" />

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true" >

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/controlview"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom|fill_horizontal"
                    android:background="@android:color/white"
                    android:gravity="bottom"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
                    tools:ignore="UselessParent" >

                    <SeekBar
                        android:id="@+id/seekBarScroll"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/TVMainaofb" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/TVMainaofb"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:minHeight="50dp"
                        android:text="365/365\n(100%)"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
                </RelativeLayout>
            </FrameLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Its working thanks. It was not working on froyo even after changing match parent to fill parent. It was the change in arrangement of layout that solved the problem. Thanks again.

Comment: Always Welcome... AniketGupte